# How to filter entries that are not duplicates of entries from others columns in Google Sheets?

Tags: filter, google-sheets

I have a column called "Masterlist" which contains values from Lists 1, 2 and 3. It also contains values which are present only in Masterlist.

How can I filter them, like shown at the attached image in Google Sheets?

EDIT: The lists will have more than one entries.

[image]

Comment: Do you need the entries to be re-printed in E without blank cells? Or do you only need a way to look things up conveniently (which the native filter function will do)?

Comment: nvm I'll just write my answer in two cases.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

In E2, type in

```
=filter(A2:A,arrayformula(iserror(match(A2:A,B2:D2,0))))
```

Check the documentation of [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) or [`match`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) for how to use them. With `match`, be sure to include the third argument. That is an easy one to forget. `arrayformula` iterates a formula over a range. The output can be a range, in which case it will print over any un-written cells. When `arrayformula` interacts with `match`, it only iterates over the first argument, which is why this solution works.

---

EDIT: If you have a two-dimensional range to match to, you need to collapse them into a one-dimensional range using the concatenation operators such as

```
=filter(A2:A,arrayformula(iserror(match(A2:A,{B2:B4;C2:C4;D2:C4},0))))
```

You can experiment with endings without row indices and let Google Sheets select an ending index for you.

---

**Solution 2**

Use the native Filter View feature. Good for the scenarios where you don't need to separately print a list of the unique values in "masterlist".

Go to Data -> Create Filter View

Use the relevant help pages to navigate yourself. I can see a few ways to implement what you desire, including

- filter by value on the same column (selecting the actual values manually);
- filter by value on a "helper column" where you include a formula in the cells to check whether the content in "masterlist" belongs to the list you want to check against. You can use the `match` and `iserror` combo here;
- custom formula using a similar formula as above.

If your column A, ie. the "masterlist", is something a user would add to, then Data Validation can be used to good effect in conjunction with Filter View.

Comment: Unforutently when I'm using Solution 1, it doesn't work after I change `=filter(A2:A,arrayformula(iserror(match(A2:A,B2:D2,0))))` to `=filter(A2:A,arrayformula(iserror(match(A2:A,B2:D,0))))`

Comment: If you have such a need, you need to describe it in your question.

Comment: @Cowboy: In this and only case, I edited your question for you. You still need to answer my first question and clarify it in your question. To motivate answers, clarify your questions enough so that future viewers can relate their situations to yours and learn from your post. Please understand that SO is not for completing or coaching coding projects for people. Ask questions with [minimally self-contained examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).